# Linux copy file after USB is connected in Node JS / Python / C / C++

Tags: python, c++, c, node.js, linux

I am having a `config.json` file on my USB drive. I want to run the program which will wait for USB drive to connect (to the laptop/Raspberry PI 3) and copy that `config.json` file to my local file at some path (like `/home/pi/seat-controller/src`. Is it possible in Node JS? I've looked at this url https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb-detection so it fires event when USB is connected, but I don't know where to find the files of that USB. Sorry I am not so good in linux systems. If it's not possible in Node JS, is it possible in these languages: Python, C, C++?

Comment: this is OS specific... you usually use udev-rules in *nix

Comment: I am using linux (Ubuntu on my laptop and Raspbian on the Raspberry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sources of the Node JS usb-detection package, it seems that they do not store the device id or some other valuable information that could allow you to mount the USB drive. Otherwise you could combine this package with [nodeos-mount](https://github.com/NodeOS/nodeos-mount) or some other Node JS package that could actually mount the drive and you should be fine. If you are in for C++ you can just look at the source of the usb-detection package (https://github.com/MadLittleMods/node-usb-detection/blob/master/src/detection_linux.cpp) and use the same mechanism but add mounting and copying.

Comment: Great, I will take a look at this C++ , Thank you!

Comment: @JurajCarnogursky you could of course do everything from scratch in C++ but I think that the sources of the usb-detection package could be a good starting point:)

Answer (score 0):

this is os specific write a udev rules file entry

something like

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0951", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1607", RUN+="/home/grenage/auto_import.sh"
```

that tells a script to run when a usb drive is connected

take a look at this tutorial about udev-rules (it doesnt cover the RUN keyword, which is what launches your script to do whatever action)

http://weininger.net/how-to-write-udev-rules-for-usb-devices.html